# Is there a log file for RDP connections (with system-name)

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, event-log, event-viewer

Is there any possible way to know the system name of the system which has taken the system remotely? From the logs we are able to know the username (but these are generic login IDs) and the IP (but we are using DHCP, those are changing day to day).

In the Event Viewer tree on the left side under *Applications and Services Logs* -> *Windows* -> *Terminal Services-**, where * is all of the logs there. In the Terminal Service Local Session Manager Operational log we are getting the details of only IP address and username.

Is there any log where we can find the system name also?

Comment: Mmm, I thought with "[Auditing](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/windows-7-what-is-account-auditing-and-how-to-enable-it/)" on it would show your source computers hostname (in Windows XP it does work, like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lQb44.png)). But i just tested this with windows 7 and there, only the "Source Network Address" shows up in the "Security-log" :( What systemversion is the computer you login to?

Comment: I would jump on the DHCP server and check the DHCP log, then match the IP's to computers that way.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention, some of the users are connecting through VPN. so, couldn't  rely on dhcp server logs.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention, some of the users are connecting through VPN. so, couldn't  rely on dhcp server logs.

Comment: we are using windows 7 systems.

Comment: Yeah, like i already stated in my first comment, Windows 7 (unlike Windows XP) doesn't log the hostname from which you logon in the event-log (only ip). Even when i tunnel with SSH to my server it shows the ip of that server and not my home-computer so you can't trust the ip either. There is hope though. There is an environment variable set. You could see it in `cmd.exe`. Do a `set CLIENTNAME`. That's the hostname of the computer with which you logon. If there is a login-script. you could log it yourself like that (or maybe via the task-scheduler on a trigger of the event-logon via rdp)

Answer (score 7):

Well, here it goes... (this is not going to be easy ;)

First [enable auditing](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/windows-7-what-is-account-auditing-and-how-to-enable-it/) in `secpol.msc`.
I found this is needed because the other events triggered too early to get the hostname.

- Click Start and type `secpol.msc` then hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.
  the Local Security Policy window will be displayed
- now navigate to `Local Policy` > `Audit Policy`
  and right click the `Audit account logon events` policy option and choose `Properties`.
- Now check the `Success` box (failed attempts will not be logged this way)
- Exit from `secpol.msc`

Now create a VBScript-file (for example called `c:\temp\log.vbs`):
(also edit the location of the desired logfile, here `c:\temp\rdp.log`)

```
Function sessionNumber
 Dim oShell, oExec, sOutput, iUserPos, iUserLen, iStatePos
 Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 Set oExec = oShell.Exec("query session %username%")
 sOutput = LCase(oExec.StdOut.ReadAll)
 iUserPos = InStr(sOutput,LCase(oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%username%")))
 iStatePos = InStr(sOutput,"active")
 iUserLen = Len(oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%username%"))
 sessionNumber = CInt(Trim(Mid(sOutput,iUserPos+iUserLen,iStatePos-iUserPos-iUserLen)))
End Function

Function clientName
 Dim oShell
 Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 On Error Resume Next
 clientName = LCase(oShell.RegRead("HKCU\Volatile Environment\"&sessionNumber&"\CLIENTNAME"))
 If Err.Number<>0 Then
 clientName =  "unknown"
 End If
End Function

outFile="c:\temp\rdp.log"

Const ForAppending = 8

Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile=objFSO.OpenTextFile(outFile,ForAppending,True)
objFile.Write now() & " ; " & clientName & vbCrLf
objFile.Close
```

Now for the last part create a scheduled task for starting this script.

- Click Start and type `taskschd.msc` then hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.
- Choose `Create Task` in the right pane
- Name it `Logon RDP` or something
- In the Trigger-tab choose <kbd>New</kbd> and choose "Begin the task" `On an event`
- In "Log" choose `Security` and in "Event ID" type `4624`
- Hit <kbd>Ok</kbd>
- In the Action-tab choose <kbd>New</kbd> and choose "Start a program"
- In Program type `cscript.exe` and  in Add argument type `c:\temp\log.vbs`
- Hit <kbd>Ok</kbd> twice

Now when someone logs in via RDP, their hostname is logged in `c:\temp\rdp.log`

Note that also local logins will be logged (i haven't tested that yet because i'm on a remote :)
but i guess that's not a problem.

You could of course adapt the `log.vbs` to include username, remote ip... etc.

(pfew, Windows XP was a lot easier. That one just logs the hostname in the event)
Maybe someone can come up with an easier solution :)

---

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

**Edit:**

I also found that in the security-event log there are Event IDs 4624. Look for the ones with `Logon Type: 3`. It should contain the `Workstation Name` of the machine who logged in via RDP.

```
An account was successfully logged on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Logon Type:         3

New Logon:
    Security ID:        User-PC\User
    Account Name:       User
    Account Domain:     User-PC
    Logon ID:       0xcd5c10
    Logon GUID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Process Information:
    Process ID:     0x0
    Process Name:       -

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   XPS8500
    Source Network Address: -
    Source Port:        -
```

---

**Edit #2**

This is from a completely clean Windows 7 install.
(Main machine is `Test-pc` and machine with which i logged on is `XPS8500`):

[image]

Comment: is there any other way  for the above query. please help..!!!

Comment: Could you check your security-event log for every Event ID 4624 and look only at the ones with a `Logon Type: 3` in the text? I just discovered that that one also should have the correct `Workstation Name:`. It's not easy to find them but the information is there.

Comment: Hello Rik, Thanks for your time. As you mentioned, i was searching for Event ID 4624 in Security-Event Log but couldn't find it. Do we need to start any service or enable something so that from next time the event id updated in security-event log? Please suggest.,

Comment: @user280724 I just checked a completely clean Windows 7 install and RDP'ed in and it showed several Event IDs 4624 in the Security-Event Log. (among them the `Logon type 3` with the `Workstation Name`). How are you searching them? (Don't use the filter at first, it can be iffy if not used right, just browse them). I added an image at the end of my answer. **Do** you have entries in your security-log? Maybe it's disabled.

Comment: I am unable to find previous logs like yesterday or even more previous days.

Comment: can we set the time span for the logs. if yes, please let me know...

Comment: You can click one event and then Properties on the right. You should see [this](http://i.imgur.com/ymSOIpl.png). What is the maximum log size? Did you have **any** events with Keywords "Audit Success" in the Security logs?

Comment: yes., i see keywords like "Audit Success" those are created every second.,

Comment: i can see the security logs for only present day only.. previous logs have been over-written by the new logs,...

Comment: **every second**? Then you have 3 options. 1) Check out **why** you have so many entries (every second) and disable a few in `secpol.msc`. 2) Increase the # of Kb the log keeps. (click on properties in the right pane and set a new number). You can also choose "Archive the old" but i'm not sure where they end up. 3) Use my method of logging the EventID 4624 to a separate file (which won't be deleted). You can skip the first step of activating Auditing because it is already on.